# Converting and save images as JPG in IMCE module during uploading?

Tags: media, files, performance

How to convert PNG to JPG when user upload images with IMCE ?
This is neccessary for disk space optimization. If it is possible to convert with any module or to execute Image Style tell me please.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in this way:

- download [ImageCache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) module and enable Color Actions    module
- create image style "Change file format Convert to: jpg"
- download and install [IMCE Image Style](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/yingtho/2299505) module
- on the IMCE Image Style administration page select necessary style

And we need to add custom submit function

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
 function mymodule_form_imce_upload_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   array_unshift($form['fset_upload']['upload']['#submit'], "mymodule_upload_form_submit");
 }

/**
 * Change uploaded image extension.
 */
 function mymodule_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   if ($_FILES['files']['type']['imce'] == 'image/png' &&    $form_state['values']['imce_image_style']['optimize_image'] != '0') {
      $_FILES['files']['name']['imce'] = str_replace('.png', '.jpg', $_FILES['files']['name']['imce']);
   }
 }
```

Comment: thank you. IMCE Image Style really execute Image Style that I've made that has name "tojpg" and convert png to jpg very well. But my module with your code does not rename files, the extension rests .png. I remove code "&&    $form_state['values']['imce_image_style']['optimize_image'] != '0'" but anyway extensin rests .png. please how to correct this. and more questions^ How to mark up my Image Style by default? And how to hide this options for no-admin users that they cannot disable conversion?

Comment: and tell me please how to use Devel function to view this variables? when I add the line dpm($_FILES); it does not show me info cause modal window hides quckly

Comment: "But my module with your code does not rename files, the extension rests .png. I remove code "&& $form_state['values']['imce_image_style']['optimize_image'] != '0'" but anyway extensin rests .png" it is strange, all work fine for me. Maybe you have made typo somewhere? Try to use 'watchdog' function in order to check if your custom code is executed.

Comment: I paste dpm() function and it show any message in modal window so I can say: my module works. but has no effect.<?php
 function imce_png_to_jpg_form_imce_upload_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   array_unshift($form['fset_upload']['upload']['#submit'], "imce_png_to_jpg_upload_form_submit");
 }


 function imce_png_to_jpg_upload_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state);
   if ($_FILES['files']['type']['imce'] == 'image/png') {
      $_FILES['files']['name']['imce'] = str_replace('.png', '.jpg', $_FILES['files']['name']['imce']);
   }
 }
?>

Comment: is it neccessary to hane IMCE Upload or  may be IMCE plupload is ok? i'm using 2nd

Comment: I use default IMCE button in WYSIWYG editor

Comment: oh! yes it works. but not with IMCE plupload. Now i set up IMCE Uploader instead so please how to use hook_imce_uploader_alter() https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_uploader  ?

Comment: Sorry, but I use Wysiwyg module and IMCE Wysiwyg bridge module